# How C++ compilers differentiate the token >> for binary operator, and for template

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11

My doubt is about the parser of C++ compilers as Clang, how the compilers handle the operator `>>` to know when it is a binary operator and when it is closing a template like: `std::vector<std::tuple<int, double>>`, I imagine that is done in parser time, so the better way to solve that is on lexical or use only > as token, and solve the problem in the grammar parser?

Comment: See __right-angle brackets__ in here: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html and also read: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1757.html

Comment: I remember times where `>>` simply didn't work for templates. Had to write `> >`

Comment: I didn't know you were allowed to do that

Comment: It was a c++11 fix. The compilers were handling it anyway in order to produce sensible syntax checking for the template body. I think there was another one they fixed. At the same time they insisted on adding a space between concatenated strings You have to write `"error in: " __FILE__` now instead of `"Error in: "__FILE__`.

Comment: @GemTaylor Yes, I've experienced that last one.

Comment: @gem: the change to string literal parsing was done to enable [user-defined literals](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#UD-literals).

Comment: Indeed it was. It is still irritating. The C++ committee give with one hand and take away with the other :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually quite simple: if there is an open template bracket visible, a `>` closes it, even if the `>` would otherwise form part of a `>>` operator. (This doesn't apply to `>` characters which are part of other tokens, such as `>=`.) This change to C++ syntax was part of C++11, and is described in paragraph 3 of §13.3 [temp.names].

An open template bracket is not visible if the `>` is inside a parenthetically nested syntax. So the `>>` in both  `T<sizeof a[x >> 1]>` and `T<(x >> 1)>` are right shift operators, while `T<x >> 1>` probably does not parse as expected.

The two implementation strategies are both workable, depending on where you want to put the complexity. If the lexer never generates a `>>` token; the parser can check that the `>` tokens in `expr '>'  '>' expr` are adjacent by looking at their source locations. There will be a shift-reduce conflict, which will have to be resolved in favour of reducing the template parameter list. This works because it happens that there  is no ambiguity created by separating `>>` into two tokens, but that's not a general rule: `a + ++ b` is different from `a ++ + b`; if the lexer were  only generating `+` tokens, that would be ambiguous.

It's not too complicated to resolve the issue with a lexer hack, if you are prepared to have your lexer track parenthesis depth. That means the lexer has to know whether a `<` is a template bracket or a comparison operator, but it is quite possible that it does.

This is the more interesting question (at least imho): how is  a `<` recognised as a template bracket rather than a less-than operator? Here there really is semantic feedback: it is a template bracket if it follows a name which designates a template.

This is not a simple determination. The name could be a class or union member, and even a member of a specialisation of a templated class or union. In the latter case, it might be necessary to calculate the values of compile-time constant expressions and then do template deduction in order to decide what the name designates.

Comment: The story doesn't end there, as I just found out. `T<x>>y` can be a [valid parse](https://godbolt.org/g/Cr9Z1F) even if `T` is  a template. It is a pathological case, IMHO, and I'd always recommend adding an extra space.

Comment: @arne: i always recommend surrounding binary operators with spaces. But that's a style question. Do you feel that my description was on some way misleading about that example?

Comment: Determining whether a name is a *template-name* has become a bit harder with C++17 because of ADL lookup for things like `f<1>()`.