# How does C++ differentiate between > operators and two >> tokens in a row (i.e. in a template)?

Tags: c++, parsing

So if I understand correctly, in C++ we have a bit-shift operator:

```
int a  = 1024;
a = a >> 1;
```

And we can also have two `>` tokens in a row in some contexts, i.e. in a template:

```
Foo<Bar<int>> x = ...
```

How do C++ parsers differentiate between those cases?  Do C++ lexers need to have context information when they're parsing tokens to know whether they're parsing a pair of angle braces or something?

Comment: Well, the c++ compilers weren't guaranteed to distinguish these before th c++11 standards. In case of templates you had to add a whitespace character between the closing angle brackets.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331315/double-closing-angle-brackets-generate-syntax-error-in-specific-case

Comment: Short answer: yes, lexers use context information. Things get rather dicy when `>>` is truly ambiguous.

Comment: Unfortunate C++ syntax choice for templates, but way too late to fix it now.  I wish C++ would have used a template syntax like, say, `Foo!(Bar!int)` but that ship has long since sailed.

Comment: @sam: `>>`  is never ambiguous. The problem is that it's not always easy to know whether a `<` is a less-than operator or the start of a template argument list. Although that determination requires resolving the name which precedes the `<`, a task which goes far beyond what lexers are generally responsible for, the answer is always clear. And once that determination is made, the decision about `>>` is very simple -- if a `>` can close a template argument list, then it does so. See [this brief answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50743644/1566221).

Comment: @rici: `constexpr size_t n=2; { template<size_t> struct X:   ...  std::vector<X< 8 >> n ...` here `>>` can either terminate the template declaration, or be a part of the constant expression that gives the template parameter. You don't know until more is parsed. Completely ambiguous.

Comment: @sam: X is a template name, so the `<` following it is a template bracket. So the two `>` which follow are close brackets. Not ambiguous. If you want the `>>` to be a shift operator, you have to use parentheses.

Comment: Section 13.3 para 3